# Randomly Assign Data

Tags: r, excel

I have a group of people that have each submitted presentations for a conference. Each presentation needs to be reviewed 7 times by the other submitter's but no submitter should review their own presentation. I would like to randomly assign each person to review 7 presentations, with each presentation only being reviewed 7 times and no person reviewing their own.

Example Data:

`DT = data.frame(First_Name = letters[1:10], Presentation = 1:10)`

I am open to doing this in either R or Excel. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How many people are in the group ??

Comment: We have 142 people

Comment: My solution will work with any number...............see below...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *Excel*:

Place the members of the group in column **A**:

[image]

and run this macro:

```
Sub Reviewers()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long, rA As Range

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rA = Range("A1:A" & N)
    '
    '----------------------------------PART 1
    '
    For i = 1 To N
        j = i + 1
        rA.Copy Cells(1, j)
        Cells(i, j).Delete shift:=xlUp
    Next i
    '
    '---------------------------------PART 2
    '

    For i = 2 To N + 1
        Call SkrambleRange(Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(N - 1, i)))
    Next i
End Sub

    Sub SkrambleRange(rng As Range)
        Dim arr(), r As Range, i As Long
        ReDim arr(1 To rng.Count)
        i = 1
        For Each r In rng
            arr(i) = r.Value
            i = i + 1
        Next r

        Call Shuffle(arr)

        i = 1
        For Each r In rng
            r.Value = arr(i)
            i = i + 1
        Next r
    End Sub

    Public Sub Shuffle(InOut() As Variant)
        Dim i As Long, j As Long
        Dim tempF As Double, Temp As Variant

        Hi = UBound(InOut)
        Low = LBound(InOut)
        ReDim Helper(Low To Hi) As Double
        Randomize

        For i = Low To Hi
            Helper(i) = Rnd
        Next i


        j = (Hi - Low + 1) \ 2
        Do While j > 0
            For i = Low To Hi - j
              If Helper(i) > Helper(i + j) Then
                tempF = Helper(i)
                Helper(i) = Helper(i + j)
                Helper(i + j) = tempF
                Temp = InOut(i)
                InOut(i) = InOut(i + j)
                InOut(i + j) = Temp
              End If
            Next i
            For i = Hi - j To Low Step -1
              If Helper(i) > Helper(i + j) Then
                tempF = Helper(i)
                Helper(i) = Helper(i + j)
                Helper(i + j) = tempF
                Temp = InOut(i)
                InOut(i) = InOut(i + j)
                InOut(i + j) = Temp
              End If
            Next i
            j = j \ 2
        Loop
    End Sub
```

**Part 1** produces a list of reviewers for each submitter.  So column **B** is the reviewer list for Mary Smith *(Mary Smith's own name has been removed)*; column **C** is the reviewer list for Patricia Johnson, etc.
**Part 2** shuffles each of the reviewer columns.:

[image]

To get the 7 reviewers for Mary Smith, pull the first 7 names from column **B**.
To get the 7 reviewers for Patricia Johnson, pull the first 7 names from column **C**, etc.

Comment: Using this solution, does each reviewer have 7 other presentations to review? EG: Mary Smith has 7 people review her proposal, but also has 7 proposals to review.

Comment: @josh453  That is why I use the full data for column **B**.....use **B1** through **B7** for the first paper, then use **B8** through **B14** for the second paper, etc..................thus you get all 49 picks *(7 X 7)* out of the available pool.

Answer (score 0):

The `igraph` library for R has algorithms for random graph generation. It sounds like you want to connect each person to 7 other people randomly, say for a group of 10 total people. This could be represented as a graph with 10 vertices, each with degree 7.

Here is one such method in the library

```
library(igraph)
plot(g <- sample_degseq(rep(7,10),method="vl"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using linear programming. (inspired by [Randomly assign elements repeatedly to a limited number of groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35804469/randomly-assign-elements-repeatedly-to-a-limited-number-of-groups/35805005#35805005) and https://acoppock.github.io/subpages/Random_Assignment_Subject_To_Constraints.html)

```
library(lpSolve)
library(tidyverse)

df <- 
  # get all possible person-presentation combinations
  expand.grid(person = letters[1:10], presentation = 1:10) %>%
  mutate(person_number = match(person, letters)) %>%
  # throw out self-matches
  filter(presentation != person_number)

# Two constraints:
# each presentation is reviewed 7 times.
# Each person conducts 7 reviews

first <- t(sapply(1:10, function(i) as.numeric(df$presentation == i)))
second <- t(sapply(letters[1:10], function(i) as.numeric(df$person == i)))

const.mat <- rbind(first, second)
const.dir <- rep(c("=", "="), c(10, 10))
const.rhs <- rep(c(7, 7), c(10, 10))

# This is the acutal stochastic part
random_objective <- runif(ncol(const.mat))

mod <- lp(
  direction = "max",
  objective.in = random_objective,
  const.mat = const.mat,
  const.dir = const.dir,
  const.rhs = const.rhs,
  all.bin = TRUE
)

df$assign_review <- mod$solution

with(df, table(assign_review))
with(df, table(assign_review, presentation))
with(df, table(assign_review, person))
```

This produces output as desired:

```
> with(df, table(assign_review, presentation))
             presentation
assign_review 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
            0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  2
            1 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7  7
> with(df, table(assign_review, person))
             person
assign_review a b c d e f g h i j
            0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
            1 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
```